# What can the order of the generators of a non abelian group tell us about the group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

> What can the order of the generators of a non abelian group tell us about the group?

For example, if we have $G$ as the non abelian group of order $8$, representing the quaternions;
$$
G=\{s,t\mid s^4=t^4=1, s^2=t^2, st=ts^{-1}\}
$$

and we consider $N$, the subgroup of ${\rm Perm}(G)$ generated by $\lambda(s),\rho(t)$ where $\lambda,\rho\in {\rm Perm}(G)$ define the left and right regular representations respectively.

I know that $\lambda(s)$ and $\rho(t)$ both have order $4$ but it's not immediately obvious to me what $N$ would look like. By lagrange's theorem, $N$ must be a multiple of $4$ and since $\lambda(s), \rho(t)$ are distinct $N$ must be at least $8$ (?)

How would we know the exact structure of $N$ without explicitly calculating each element?

Comment: $N$ is a subgroup. How can it be at least $8$?

Comment: $N$ is a subgroup of $Perm(G)\subseteq S_8$ and $\mid S_8\mid =8!$

Comment: Note that a cyclic group of order $4$ can be written as $\langle s,t \:|\: s^4 = 1 = t^2, s^2 = t \rangle$ and even though $s$ and $t$ have distinct orders, the order of the group is smaller than the product of their orders. Moreover, if you have a group given by generators and relations it is not always possible to find the actual order of the generators from the relations given. For example, in the group $\langle s,t \:|\: s^4 = 1 = t^3, s^2 = t \rangle$, at first glance it would seem that $s$ has order $4$ and $t$ has order $3$, however, it turns out, that $s$ is of order $2$ and $t =1$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch What you write is true, but how is it relevant to the question?

Comment: The question should be copied inside the text.

Comment: The order ($\ge 2$) of generators give very little information (except when there's a single generator, or two generators of order 2). Indeed these orders being given, the group can be finite of arbitrary large order, and can also be infinite, and moreover every countable group embeds into such a group (with the given generator orders).

Comment: @DerekHolt The OP has a group given by generators and relations and claims to know the order of the generators. I wanted to make sure that they are aware of the difficulty of obtaining the orders of the generators in general and that they do not think they could always read them off from the relations given. Furthermore, the OP wants to use the orders of generators to obtain a lower bound for the group order and I wanted to explain that you cannot naively take the product of distinct generator orders for this.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch But this a completely standard presentation of the quaternion group $Q_8$, and the OP clearly knows this, so I am not sure why it should be queried. Perhaps the problem here is that it is unclear what is being asked.

Comment: @DerekHolt Of course, in the example given there is a lot more information present (i.e. we know the group) and there is no real issue. I was under the impression that the OP wants to generalize from this to other group presentations where things are not so simple. But I might be wrong, of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a two generated group $G=\langle s, t\rangle$, then the two orders $p=o(s), q=o(t)$ are not enough to conclude very much about the group. In particular, the free product $\mathbb{Z}_p\ast\mathbb{Z}_q$ is infinite with generators of the specified orders, but there are in general many non-abelian finite groups $G=\langle s, t\rangle$ whose generators have the prescribed orders (e.g. assuming $1<p\leq q$, take $s=(1, 2, \ldots, p)$ and $t=(2, ..., q+1)$ in the symmetric group $S_{q+1}$).

The exception here is when $o(s)=2=o(t)$, then $G=\langle s, t\rangle$ is dihedral: here $\mathbb{Z}_2\ast\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the infinite dihedral group, and all its non-abelian quotients are dihedral groups.

However, the *three* orders $o(s), s(t), o(st)$ *can* be enough to conclude that your group is finite: if $1/o(s)+1/s(t)+1/o(st)>1$ then $G=\langle s, t\rangle$ is a finite group. (To see this, combine Sections [2.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group#The_spherical_case) and [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group#Von_Dyck_groups) of Wikipedia's article on triangle groups.)

Answer (score 1):

In any group $G$, $\lambda(G)$ and $\rho(G)$ centralize each other - in fact they are equal to each others centralizers in ${\rm Sym}(G)$.

In your example $s^2 = t^2 \in Z(G)$, so $\rho(s^2) = \lambda(t^2)$ and hence $\langle \lambda(s),\rho(t) \rangle$ is abelian of order $8$ (it is isomorphic to $C_4 \times C_2$).

Comment: If I understand properly, you are saying that $\lambda(G)$ and $\rho(G)$ commute in $Sym(G)=Perm(G)$ and that $s^2=t^2$ commute with all of $G$, which implies $\rho(s^2)=\lambda(t^2)$ and so $\langle λ(s),ρ(t)\rangle$ is abelian. 

What I don't understand now  is how you jumped from  $\rho(s^2)=\lambda(t^2)$ to it being of order 8. Could you please fill in the details in between? 

To understand the group you need to understand how generators interact with each other and elements of the group. If you weren't familiar with the group, how would you approach this?

Comment: It is generated by two cyclic groups of order $4$ with intersection of order $2$, so it has to be $C_4 \times C_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Relatively little.  The fact that one has finite-order generators does not imply that the group itself is finite; this is the (in)famous [Burnside problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem) solved by Golod & Shafarevich.  Golod & Shafarevich's example requires the generators to have unbounded order; classifying the groups with bounded exponent is a major area of open research.  If we know that the finitely-presented group is in fact finite, then one can at least control the group, but this required a [Fields medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem#Restricted_Burnside_problem) to show.

I don't know enough about Zelmanov's Fields-medal–winning work to try to summarize it here; hopefully this is enough keywords to start Googling.